# Memory leak with malloc and fgetc

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm having some trouble reading a like from user using malloc and getchar. I get the result, however, I get memory leaks using valgrind. I am pretty clueless in this and have asked my classmates and mentors, but none seem to find out why.

```
char *ReadLineFile(FILE *infile){
   int i=0;
   char c;
   char *newStringLine;
   newStringLine = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
   while( (c = fgetc(infile)) != '\n' ){
        newStringLine[i++] = c;
        realloc(newStringLine, (sizeof(char) * (i+1)));
   }
   newStringLine[i] = '\0';
   return newStringLine;
}
```

Valgrind gives me several errors, including Invalid write/read of 1, and invalid realloc.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: That was a fast reply! I tried not casting it, however, I kept getting the same leaks and errors.

Comment: You should use the return value of `realloc`. You throw it away.

Comment: @ricknaght  Totally ignore the reference about casting the return of malloc. There is an answer of a low-qualified programmer that does not know how to write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of `realloc()` is erroneous.

`realloc()`, if successful, frees the passed pointer and **returns** a new pointer with the allocated memory. You need to

- catch the return value of `realloc()` in a temporary pointer,
- check against NULL to ensure success and then

  - If returned pointer is not NULL, i.e., reallocation is successful, use the new pointer.
  - If the returned pointer is NULL, make some decisions and you can keep using the old pointer (passed as argument).

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> The `realloc` function **deallocates the old object** pointed to by `ptr` **and returns a
>   pointer to a new object** that has the size specified by `size`. [....]

and,

> [...] If memory for the new object cannot be
>   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Otherwise, in case, `realloc()` is successful, you are (*most probably*) trying to use an already free-d memory, which , of course, causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Uh-oh, and did I mention, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)?

Comment: " in case, realloc() is successful, you are trying to use an already free-d memory": not necessarily, if the system just increases the size of the block without moving the memory (which often happens). But it's roulette.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, that's not guaranteed, right? better play safe. :)

Comment: of course! but I've seen other questions like this where OP could run his code up to some point where memory is moved. False impression that it's working!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and that is precisely sir, what I want to avoid. Added a note, though.  :)

Comment: That worked! As suggested, I used a temp variable, and then simply assigned it back to my newStringLine pointer. This definitely taught me a lesson! Thanks!